# Can you point all of a TLD towards Localhost in a hostsfile?

Tags: hosts-file

Is it possible to point all of a TLD (like .dev), towards localhost with the hostsfile and without having to set up a local DNS server? Would be awesome for local web development!

Answer (score 4):

The `hosts` facility in most operating systems does not support wildcard functionality; you would need to write (or find) a [NSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) library (or whatever equivalent is used on Windows or OS X) to provide the names.